# In Swift 3, UIEdgeInsetsMake is available

Tags: swift3

CGRectMake , CGPointMake, CGSizeMake, CGRectZero, CGPointZero is unavailable in Swift3. but UIEdgeInsetsMake, NSMakeRange, etc available in Swift3.
Why didn't Apple remove these?

Answer (score 10):

They are not removed.  They are renamed.  You now use the initializer syntax instead of a factory method:

```
UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
```

And the constants are now a static property of the type

```
UIEdgeInsets.zero
```

Comment: Thank you for comment. Why is UIEdgeInsetsMake available?.

Comment: @shoheiyokoyama swift3 functions has been evolved as you must include parameter name in every paramters of a function. UIEdgeInsetsMake job was the same. Full [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/e4328889a9643100177aef19f6f428855c5d0cf2/proposals/0046-first-label.md)